# I can't get attachments, from the gmail API

Tags: c#, gmail

For days the api stopped working and the method to obtain the attachments only returns the error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Internal error encountered.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "backendError"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

This is the documentation of the method, from here you can also perform a test

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages.attachments/get?hl=es-419

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB9sg.png

That is the same error that I receive with the method that I have implemented, it is necessary to take into consideration that this method has been working for more than 4 years without problems

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7bMY.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.